# Domain attribute in the <httpCookies> element. What does it mean when setting it to "" or leave out?

Tags: asp.net

For the  element in the Web.config for an ASP.NET WebForms App.

What difference does it make when I set the Domain attribute to be "" compared to a valid string, e.g ".site.local" ?

Does set the attribute to be "" the same as leaving it out completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you do not need to set domain attribute.

You need to set domain if you want to share a cookie between different **Sub-Domains**.

*For example, if you set domain as example.com, you can share cookie between a.example.com and b.example.com*